# Piping file contents to remote file over SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh

I am trying to share an SSH public key with a remote server using Powershell. Typically, in Linux environments, using Bash, I would use `cat` and a pipe to append the contents of the file, like so:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@machine 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

However, I am communicating between Windows 10 hosts using the SSH feature in Windows 10, so do not have access to GNU utilities.

Instead, I am trying to use Powershell. I currently have the following Powershell code:

```
Get-Content ~\.ssh\id_ed25519.pub | ssh user@machine "'$_' | Out-File -FilePath ~\.ssh\authorized_keys -Append"
```

This runs without error but the file on the remote machine is empty. How would I go about appending my public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote machine?

I may be approaching this problem from the wrong direction; most of my shell scripting experience is in Bash on Linux. If there is a cleaner Powershell solution, I would love feedback!

**CLARIFICATION**: I am using PowerShell as the default shell on my remote Windows host.

Comment: I think it would just be `Get-Content ~\.ssh\id_ed25519.pub -raw |ForEach-Object{ ssh user@machine "$_ >> ~\.ssh\authorized_keys" }`

Comment: Powershell doesn't have a `>>`; I get an error about `>>` not being a cmdlet.

Comment: Except you're not really using PowerShell, you're using ssh, you're simply executing it from within PowerShell. If you want to use PowerShell cmdlets you will need to run PowerShell within your SSH session.

Comment: Good point, I did not specify that I have PowerShell set as the default shell on my remote Windows host. I will update the question.

Comment: `id_rsa` is the private key. `id_rsa.pub` is the public key. The public key should be in `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Forgot the `pub` at the end; question updated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by getting rid of the pipe after `Get-Content` and evaluating the `Get-Content` call in the command I run with SSH:

```
ssh user@machine "'$(Get-Content .\.ssh\id_ed25519.pub)' | Out-File -FilePath ~\.ssh\authorized_keys -Append"
```